# DELL Latitude 7490 no hard drive available for boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, dell-latitude

I needed several tries to install a Windows 10 on an empty DELL Latitude 7490. After giving up with a self created USB stick I bought an installation DVD and lo and behold Windows was installed. Or I thought so.

To be able to boot from an external DVD I changed the settings in the BIOS.

Now I have the situation, that the laptop boots, when the external DVD with the installation DVD is plugged in, but not when it is plugged out.

When I start the Laptop with F12 I get the following menu:

```
Boot mode is set to: LEGACY EXTERNAL DEVICES: Secure Boot:Off
   Onboard NIC
UEFI Boot:
   **Onboard NIC (IPV4)** 
   Onboard NIC (IPV6)
OTHER OPTIONS:
   BIOS Setup
   BIOS Flash Update
   Diagnostics
   Intel Management Engine BIOS Extension
   change Boot Mode Settings
```

When I go into the BIOS Settings to the "Boot Sequence" menu item I have :

- Onboard NIC
- CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
- USB Storage Device
- Diskette drive

With "Boot List Option" I have activated "Legacy External devices", if I choose "UEFI" I have only the 2 Onboard NIC choices above.

However what I don't have is a hard drive.

**How can I boot from my laptop's hard drive?**

I am quite sure that I installed something, because when Windows starts it shows Firefox and Chrome, which I installed manually.

BIOS General System Information says:

```
M.2 SATA = (none)
M.2 PCIe SSD-0 = 291S10B4TPBQ
```

Comment: Get Dell's Hardware Diagnostics on bootable USB and test the hardware. May be a bad disk

Comment: Could be, but the hard disk was alive before I completely formatted it and threw off everything, which was on it before. So while this is a possibility I fear I have messed up some settings. 
But I have a knoppix here, with which I might also be able to check the disk.

Comment: Maybe see if you can (windows) format it after testing with knoppix.

Comment: That is how I formatted the hard disk in the first place. I just added the SSD info to my post.

Comment: The standard way to install Windows 10 using "Create Windows 10 installation media", https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10. Start with an empty USB, between 16 and 32 GB, unpartitioned or with FAT32. Keep Secure Boot *on* when installing.

Comment: Dr.Moishe that is exactly what I tried first. It didn't work. 
But I don't see how that would solve my problem now.

Comment: UEFI boot wont list your NVMe drive if it doesnt have a valid boot partition. When you boot using the installation DVD, does windows installer see your HDD ? Have you been able to succesfuly install windows and if so, when you boot using the DVD and skip installation, does it boot succesfuly ? During installation, make sure you are using GPT for your NVMe drive and not MBR, especially if you're booting in non legacy mode.

Comment: @Silbee If I boot with the DVD connected I see installed software , which didn't come with the installation DVD e.g. Chrome and Firefox, which I installed manually after the Windows Installation. I will check if I can access the hard disk in that case.

Comment: Yes if I boot with the DVD connected I see my 2 partitions on the hard drive C and D and also the DVD drive as E.
C contains the Windows 10 installation.
C and D contains data and it seems that both have a windows installed. When I boot it also offers me 2times windows 10 on two volumes. What a mess!

Comment: What I did now is a complete re-install including removing the existing partitions and creating a singe new one. 
After removing the DVD I am back to "no Boot device found" 
During the installation Windows claimed to have created a small partition for boot. 
I still think the BIOS setting are my problem

Comment: Do you think a BIOS upgrade could help to get factory settings back?

Comment: Your PC has UEFI, not BIOS. And although it shouldn't be needed, there are reasons for releasing new firmware versions - new hardware support, bug fixes, etc. - so it won't hurt updating to the latest version available at Dell. But it won't5 solve any setup problem. Start by disabling CSM/Legacy/"BIOS" mode support to assure you're correctly booting the installation media in UEFI mode. Install after blanking the drive - remove all partitions - and let the installer decide to create the new partitions. If you manually created a single one that's already wrong.

Comment: @ChaganAuto I try to install from an external DVD, which is connected via USB. When I deactivate all Legacy stuff, my DVD device isn't available for install.

Comment: The year is 2023, not 2003. Sorry to be blunt but that's how it is. Any modern OS is to be installed with a USB stick. Using optical media nowadays is asking for trouble, namely same installers may force Legacy mode. AFAIK, current Windows on DVD should be able to install in the proper UEFI mode - here they say Windows 10 on DVD can install in both modes: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-make-a-bootable-windows-10-dvd-that-supports/dffd2c3c-1deb-4a78-ae18-582adcc15ed2 - but you should make an USB stick as already suggested. The link also explains about the GPT need.

Comment: And in any case *support for legacy (USB) devices* that you may need to enable to use the DVD drive has nothing to do with firmware/OS installation modes where you shouldn't enable CSM/Legacy. How it, the installation media, boots is how it installs. Again, you want to assure it boots in UEFI mode, period. Then you have to make sure the target drive has the correct partitioning type - GPT - and the installer does the rest for you. This is the only proper way to install Windows 10 in your laptop, the same way it was factory installed.